# How to highlight occurrences of a search term in text in Visual Studio 11 / 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How to highlight occurrences of a search term in text in Visual Studio 11 / 2012?  There are solutions in VS 2010 and 2008, any one know of one for VS2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix mentioned in the solution is to download the SelectionHighlight.vsix file then.

1. Change the Extension to .zip
2. Open the zip file and edit the manifest file in a text editor.
3. Change the Visual Studio Version attribute to 11.
4. After saving the file back into the zip, change the extension back to .vsix

Just move forward with installing the file and you are set.

Answer (score 0):

okay... just checked a plugin for VS2010 and they have a "Fix" for 2012.  Check the Q and A here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb